# Cross-browser, mobile-centric draggable element using AngularJS or plain javascript (without jQuery)

Tags: angularjs, mobile, draggable, drag, hammer.js

I'm using **[angular-gestures](https://github.com/wzr1337/angular-gestures)** and I'm happy with it because it's basic gestures are working good on all my devices. But I can't find a docs about using `hm-drag`.
I want to have a simple draggable element and I'm not using jQuery. There is a nice article which demonstrates `hm-drag` usage on pure `Hammer.js` - [Multitouch with Hammer.js](http://www.appliness.com/multitouch-with-hammer-js/)

```
OnDragStart = function(event) {
    var touches = event.originalEvent.touches || [event.originalEvent];
    ...
};
```

But I can't find an `originalEvent` nor `touches` property with **`angular-gestures`**:

```
$scope.onDragStart = function ($event) {
    console.log($event);
    ...
};
```

displays:

```
bubbles 
cancelable
currentTarget
eventPhase
explicitOriginalTarget
isTrusted
originalTarget
target
timeStamp
type
```

Is it possible to retrieve `originalEvent` or `touches` property with **`angular-gestures`**?
Or is there any other way to create a cross-browser, mobile-centric draggable element using `AngularJS` or plain `javascript` (without `jQuery`)?